# Pesquisa mysql com apenas um dos campos selecionados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estou com uma dúvida sobre como organizar essa informação, eu tenho dois selects no meu código, que ao usuário escolher os dois ele, gera a tabela buscando quem tem as duas informações, porém eu gostaria que a pesquisa fosse feita mesmo se o usuário selecionar apenas um dos dois campos

Esse é o código do request

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
            $id_categoria = $_POST['id_categoria'];
            $id_sub_categoria = $_POST['id_sub_categoria'];
            $pagina = 1;
            $_SESSION['id_categoria'] = $id_categoria;
            $_SESSION['id_sub_categoria'] = $id_sub_categoria;
```

E no caso esse é query executada

```
                    $result_empresas = "SELECT * 
                                FROM clientes 
                                WHERE (categoria_id = '$id_categoria' OR '$id_categoria' IS NULL) AND 
                                ( subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' OR '$id_sub_categoria' IS NULL) AND
                                ('$id_sub_categoria' IS NOT NULL OR '$id_categoria' IS NOT NULL)
                                 LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
```

Agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result_empresas = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE 
                   (categoria_id = '$id_categoria' OR '$id_categoria' = NULL) AND
                   (subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' OR '$id_sub_categoria' = NULL)                              
                   LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
```

Suponho que apenas isso deva funcionar, caso não funcione com `NULL`, use `''`.

```
$result_empresas = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE 
                   (categoria_id = '$id_categoria' OR '$id_categoria' = '') AND
                   (subcategoria_id = '$id_sub_categoria' OR '$id_sub_categoria' = '')                              
                   LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
```

Comment: Não funcionou nesse caso, se eu seleciono apenas um dos seletcs, ele não gera a tabela

Comment: Tenta do segundo jeito q coloquei no exemplo